# Why versions of product with the same UpgradeCode were shipped as different products

Tags: wix, wix3, windows-installer

I use Wix v3.9, and for my product I setup hard-coded Upgrade code, as it's [the unique ID to identify a family of a product](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx).

For Product code I use the '*', in order to generate different IDs for different versions.

During testing of installations, I rebuilt my installer several times, so a new ProductCode was generated for each build.

And now, after testing of several installations, I see from 'Control Panel -> Programs' that **my product is installed several times**. Why?

Comment: From the link which is provided within my question, I learned that if MSI was built with different ProductCode and different PackageCode, the installer would think that it is a NEW product. Is it the answer? WiX doc says that when compiling a product, I should not set Package Code explicitly, so I don't do it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MSI is only uninstalled by a newer MSI if the Upgrade table is set to remove the matching UpgradeCode & ProductVersion range. The easiest way to do this in Wix is to use the MajorUpgrade element.

Comment: I use this element this way: <MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

Comment: I checked the doc for the [MajorUpgrade](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) element - in my case MSI treated versions of my product as two different products because of the fact that _by default the AllowSameVersionUpgrades is No_. So, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Then again, wix might ignore it somehow and you'll end up with multiple entries anyway...